# Elasticsearch: Append new elements to nested array of objects

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to add new items to a nested array of objects from a specific document.
I have searched and it seems updates with a partial document doesn't support what I need, it replaces the entire array with the new elements.
So I went for a scripted update, which worked as expected via REST API:

```
PUT /transactions
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "userId": { "type": "keyword" },
                "transactions": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "date": { "type": "date" },
                        "amount": { "type": "double" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

POST /transactions/_doc/1
{
    "userId": "123",
    "transactions": [
        { "date": "2019-07-15T10:32:02Z", "amount": 122 },
        { "date": "2019-07-17T22:09:43Z", "amount": 560 }
    ]
}

POST /transactions/_doc/1/_update
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.transactions.addAll(params.transactions)",
        "params": {
            "transactions": [
                { "date": "2019-07-14T21:10:22Z", "amount": 890 },
                { "date": "2019-07-15T15:56:18Z", "amount": 54 }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I took the same script to my Java application, this is what the code looks like:

```
List<Transaction> transactions = Collections.singletonList(new Transaction(320));

Script script = new Script(
    Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_TYPE, Script.DEFAULT_SCRIPT_LANG,
    "ctx._source.transactions.addAll(params.transactions);",
    Collections.singletonMap("transactions", transactions));

transportClient
    .prepareUpdate("transactions", "_doc", 1)
    .setFetchSource(false);
    .setScript(script);
    .get();
```

When the code above is executed, I get the following remote exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: can not write type [class com.example.model.Transaction]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeGenericValue(StreamOutput.java:713)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.lambda$static$9(StreamOutput.java:599)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeGenericValue(StreamOutput.java:711)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.lambda$static$11(StreamOutput.java:621)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeGenericValue(StreamOutput.java:711)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamOutput.writeMap(StreamOutput.java:494)
    at org.elasticsearch.script.Script.writeTo(Script.java:533)
    ...
```

If I serialize the list into a string I get this exception instead:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NotSerializableExceptionWrapper: class_cast_exception: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.Collection
```

Finally, my question is how can I accomplish this with the Java API (Transport Client, Elasticsearch 6.3.2)?

One alternative is to fetch the whole document, deserialize it, append a new transaction and then update the whole document, but it seems overkill and probably degrades the performance.

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: As stated in the question, 6.3.2.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Slipped by me. Dows the answer help though?

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you!

Comment: Awesome... Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a curiosity look at the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/80b2a220f735255ad95158e713404fc34cdb9787/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/io/stream/StreamOutput.java#L803), from the `writeGenericValue` method, it looks like ES doesn't support writes of any custom objects except the ones handled in the multiple if else statements (Object[], List, Map, ReadableInstant, BytesReference).

From the stack trace it looks like `script.writeTo` is trying to write `Transaction` objects into the output stream and failing to do so. Converting the `Transaction` objects to individual Maps and then sending it might solve the problem.