# Pass objects inScript params to Elasticsearch Java update API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-java-api

Trying to append object to list field in an Elasticsearch document. This works, but I cannot figure the Java code with the right type for the "events" value that Elasticsearch will accept:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:55683/index-name/_doc/filePrincipalId_0/_update' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.events.add(params.event)",
        "params": {
            "event":  {
                "id": "eventId_1",
                "ponies": true
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Whatever I pass in ghd `Map` throws some kind of type casting exception:

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [events] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value]
```

In summary, what goes in XXX in order to correctly populate the "event" value in the params map?

```
        var updateRequest = new UpdateRequest()
                .index(INDEX_NAME)
                .id(k)
                .script(new Script(
                        ScriptType.INLINE,
                        "painless",
                        "ctx._source.events.add(params.event)",
                        Map.of("event", XXX)));
```

Comment: Could you both paste the error, and a sample of the code, to be able to replicate ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that complex object handling is still a bit crude here. As suggested in [Elasticsearch: Append new elements to nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57096680/261984) the best option would be to pass a (nested) map object in the "event" param value